# React - can custom functions within a Class be split to a different file?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React (or front-end development in general given I'm a back-end oriented dev) and so far have no problems generally developing with it. However, I've been trying to find an answer to whether functions created within a class (and these functions are SPECIFIC to that class only) can be split to a different file and imported?

Let me give an example:

```
class ModuleInstance extends React.Component {
  // Initial module counter
  state = {
    moduleIndex: this.props.index,
    module: this.props.module,
    params: {
      single_assignment: this.props.module.assignments.length === 1 ? true : false,
      weightError: false,
      errorMessage: ''
    },
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.assignments !== prevProps.assignments) {
      this.setState({
        params: {
          ...this.state.params,
          single_assignment: this.state.module.assignments.length === 1 ? true : false
        }
      });
    }
  }

  onRemoveModule = () => {
    this.props.onRemoveModule(this.state.moduleIndex);
  };

  render() {}
...
```

In this example, I have a custom method "onRemoveModule". And the truth is I have a lot of those 'customs' there. It gets annoying when I need to scroll up and down when writing stuff within render() and looking at the functions above it. So my question is - can I take out the custom functions to a different file and import those to that specific class?

Comment: Hi somekid, just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps or if you need any further explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of anti-pattern, but I suppose you could do something like this:

### Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { printName } from "./utils";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Bobby"
    };
  }

  printName = printName.bind(this);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.printName}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Function outside component:

```
export const printName = function() {
  console.log(this.state.name);
};
```

Just remember to define a method in your component to use the imported function and bind it.

See codesandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tharp-e1oom

Comment: how can we do the same thing with a functional component? it is giving foo is not defined error, while foo is my external function.

Answer (score 0):

> It gets annoying when I need to scroll up and down when writing stuff within render() and looking at the functions above it.

Editor with window splitting (or ability to open the same file side-by-side) should be good enough ;) Separating methods into files almost makes no difference in editing.

---

I think you should learn about (a bit historical but IMHO still valid) concept/pattern of separation [of concerns] into ['Presentational and Container Components'](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) (often in separate folders).

Probably you should learn about [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) - state and method provider.

> `onRemoveModule = () => {
>    this.props.onRemoveModule(this.state.moduleIndex);
>   };`

Probably you can move this logic into [componentWillUnmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) - called when parent simply stops rendering this component. Also redefining this method/handler can be a premature optimization.

---

Probably we could offer better suited solutions (than workaround) if you describe more preciselly structures/requirements for your module management and usage.